# Missing Docking Options in JEdit?

Tags: ubuntu, jedit, docking

I recently re-installed jEdit (4.3.1 using Java 1.6.0_18) on Ubuntu and I noticed that since I reinstalled it, it no longer has menus that allow you to dock plugin windows around the jEdit Editor window.

*(see docked plugin on left in image bellow)*
[image]

I thought it was a plugin, but after checking the documentation I discovered otherwise.  Is there any way to get this functionality back?

In the image below I was expecting a menu that reads 
 left/top/bottom/right docking area which allows you to doc the plugin window as above, but it is missing.

[image][image]

Is there any way to get this functionality back?

Comment: You may got good answers in askubuntu.com too (but of course you should wait at least until tomorrow in here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this question a long time after I asked the question...a while ago I found the answer, so here it is:

In a jEdit floating window, on the upper left there will be an upside-down triangle that when clicked will normally display a menu with items like "Dock at Up", "Dock at Down", "Dock at Left", "Dock at Right"; if these menus do not appear, it is because the Docking Area has been disabled.  To enable the Docking Area, click:

```
View->Docking->Toggle Docking Area
```

And then return to the floating window's upside-down triangle menu, where the "Dock at <direction>" menus will appear and allow you to dock floating windows.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same problem (on Windows, but the same symptoms). In my case the problem was caused by the following line in the perspective.xml files in my .jEdit directory:

```
<VIEW PLAIN="TRUE">
```

Changing this to:

```
<VIEW PLAIN="FALSE">
```

fixed the problem.

It looks like jEdit was creating plain views by default, and perhaps docking doesn't work in plain views? (I'm speculating!) I don't know what options in the UI made my views plain in the first place. Hopefully someone who knows jEdit better can provide an explanation.

Either way, this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to dock a window from the floaty windows anymore.

The only way I know of to dock windows in jEdit is to go to the "Utilities" menu and select "Global Options". You can try `Ctrl-F12` if you like.

Under the jEdit tree menu item on the left-hand side, you'll see a "Docking" option. Hypersearch will be there, and in my experience, any other window you'd like to dock will also appear there.

New Floating instances never seem to have the option to dock.